# Wordpress Client Dashboard Menu Page

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, user-profile

I want to add a menu page on Admin as well as User Dashboard, I have developed a plugin and it is working fine on admin dashboard but it is not showing on Client/User Dashboard. May be it is due to "role" property. But I want this on client side also. Can anyone help me please,thanks in advance!

Basic purpose is that the client have to offer some products to share or download on the website form his client/user dashboard. so I need to add this functionality using a plugin and this needs to add on client dashboard to work.

```
function wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page() {
add_menu_page(
  __( 'Custom Menu Title', 'oceanwp' ), 'Offers','manage_options','ump-date-updater/ump-date-updater.php', '', 'dashicons-tickets',6);
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [WP Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) the `$capability` parameter determines whether the menu item is shown to a user. See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/) for more info on roles and capabilities, and how to create custom capabilities.

```
// run this function on your plugin activation code
function setup_capabilities()
{
    $role = get_role( 'author' ); // set this to the actual role of "User"
    $role->add_cap('see_my_custom_menu_item');
}
```

and replace `manage_options` in your code with `see_my_custom_menu_item`